Getting "Too few nodes" error

While I am trying to simulate this LM5164Q buck converter IC exported from TI, I'm getting the too few nodes error. How to rectify it?

I think you can post the LTSpice code in your question for others to try out. (I don't use it.) Format it properly using the { } button. You should also clean up your schematic, avoiding unnecessary wire crossings - especially through components.

“The” too few nodes error??? Can you show us the actual error?
